# Java method return array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

If my method return an array how can I link for it?

```
private int[] osszesVizsgalata(int currentFord){
        int[] truefalse = new int[2];
        for(int i = 0; i<currentFord-1;i++){
            if(this.ellenfelValaszai[i] == true){truefalse[1]++;}
            else{truefalse[0]++;}
        }
        return truefalse;
    }
```

This is my method and I cant call it that I can use both element of truefalse.

```
osszesVizsgalata(2)[0];
```

This is my try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare an array in the client method and initialize it with the result of this method:

```
public void clientMethod() {
    int currentFord = 2;
    int[] foo = osszesVizsgalata(currentFord);
    //code used for example purposes
    System.out.println(foo[0]);
}
```